# How to implement multiple queries with room database?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-room, android-mvvm

Im creating an android app using room database with MVVM pattern, the problem is that i cant use multiple queries when fetching data. I can fetch data once, but then i cant do it anymore.

**DAO interface:**

```
@Dao
interface StockDao {

    @Insert
    suspend fun insert(stock:Stock)

    @Update
    suspend fun update(stock:Stock)

    @Delete
    suspend fun delete(stock:Stock)

    @Query("DELETE FROM stock_table")
    suspend fun deleteAll()

    @Query("SELECT * FROM stock_table")
    fun selectAll():Flow<List<Stock>>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM stock_table WHERE isFinished = 0")
    fun selectAllUnfinished(): Flow<List<Stock>>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM stock_table WHERE isFinished = 1")
    fun selectAllFinished():Flow<List<Stock>>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM stock_table ORDER BY totalSpent DESC")
    fun selectAllOrderByDesc():Flow<List<Stock>>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM stock_table ORDER BY totalSpent ASC")
    fun selectAllOrderByAsc():Flow<List<Stock>>

}
```

**Repository:**

```
class StockRepository(private val stockDao: StockDao) {

    private lateinit var allStock: Flow<List<Stock>>


    suspend fun insert(stock: Stock) {

        stockDao.insert(stock)

    }

    suspend fun update(stock: Stock) {

        stockDao.update(stock)

    }

    suspend fun delete(stock: Stock) {

        stockDao.delete(stock)

    }

    suspend fun deleteAll() {

        stockDao.deleteAll()

    }

    fun selectAll(): Flow<List<Stock>> {

        allStock = stockDao.selectAll()

        return allStock

    }

    fun selectAllOrderByDesc(): Flow<List<Stock>> {

        allStock = stockDao.selectAllOrderByAsc()

        return allStock

    }

    fun selectAllOrderByAsc(): Flow<List<Stock>> {

        allStock = stockDao.selectAllOrderByAsc()

        return allStock

    }

    fun selectAllFinished(): Flow<List<Stock>> {

        allStock = stockDao.selectAllFinished()

        return allStock

    }

    fun selectAllUnfinished(): Flow<List<Stock>> {

        allStock = stockDao.selectAllUnfinished()

        return allStock

    }


}
```

**Viewmodel class:**

```
class StockViewModel(private val repo: StockRepository) : ViewModel() {

    companion object {

        const val ALL = 0
        const val ORDER_BY_DESC = 1
        const val ORDER_BY_ASC = 2
        const val FINISHED = 3
        const val UNFINISHED = 4

    }

    var allStocks = repo.selectAll().asLiveData()


    fun insert(stock: Stock) = viewModelScope.launch {
        repo.insert(stock)
    }

    fun update(stock: Stock) = viewModelScope.launch {
        repo.update(stock)
    }

    fun delete(stock: Stock) = viewModelScope.launch {
        repo.delete(stock)
    }

    fun deleteAll() = viewModelScope.launch {
        repo.deleteAll()
    }

    fun selectAllStockWithFilter(filter: Int): LiveData<List<Stock>> {

        when (filter) {

            ALL -> allStocks = repo.selectAll().asLiveData()
            ORDER_BY_DESC -> allStocks = repo.selectAllOrderByDesc().asLiveData()
            ORDER_BY_ASC -> allStocks = repo.selectAllOrderByAsc().asLiveData()
            FINISHED -> allStocks = repo.selectAllFinished().asLiveData()
            UNFINISHED -> allStocks = repo.selectAllUnfinished().asLiveData()
        }

        return allStocks

    }


    class StockViewModelFactory(private val repo: StockRepository) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {

        override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
            if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(StockViewModel::class.java)) {
                @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
                return StockViewModel(repo) as T
            }

            throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown viewModel class")
        }

    }


}
```

**Application class:**

```
class FinanceApplication :Application(){

    private val database by lazy {  FinanceDatabase.getInstance(this)}

    val stockRepository by lazy { StockRepository(database.stockDao()) }
}
```

**Activity using this viewmodel :**

```
class StocksActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    //Layout components
    private lateinit var binder: ActivityStocksBinding
    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var recyclerViewAdapter: StockAdapter

    //ViewModel
    private val viewModel: StockViewModel by viewModels {
        StockViewModel.StockViewModelFactory((application as FinanceApplication).stockRepository)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binder = ActivityStocksBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binder.root)
    
        fetchStocks()


    }

    private fun fetchStocks() {


        viewModel.allStocks.observe(this) {

            recyclerViewAdapter.submitList(it)

        }


    }

    private fun initRecyclerViewLayout() {


        val recyclerViewLayoutBinder = binder.includedLayout

        recyclerView = recyclerViewLayoutBinder.stocksRecyclerView
        recyclerViewAdapter = StockAdapter(this)
        recyclerView.adapter = recyclerViewAdapter
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)


    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {

        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_stock_toolbar, menu)

        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {

        when (item.itemId) {

            R.id.menu_stock_toolbar_filter_all -> viewModel.selectAllStockWithFilter(StockViewModel.ALL)
            R.id.menu_stock_toolbar_filter_maior_menor ->  viewModel.selectAllStockWithFilter(StockViewModel.ORDER_BY_DESC)
            R.id.menu_stock_toolbar_filter_menor_maior -> viewModel.selectAllStockWithFilter(StockViewModel.ORDER_BY_ASC)
            R.id.menu_stock_toolbar_filter_finalized -> viewModel.selectAllStockWithFilter(StockViewModel.FINISHED)
            R.id.menu_stock_toolbar_filter_opened -> viewModel.selectAllStockWithFilter(StockViewModel.UNFINISHED)

        }

        return true
        
        //NOTHIN HAPPENS AFTER CHOOSING ONE

    }

}
```

When i enter the activity, all the data is fetched normally, but when i click on a menu item to apply some filter on it, nothing happens, the data doesnt change. How can i fix this?

Comment: In `StocksActivity.fetchStocks()`, the initial "all" results are displayed by `observe()`'ing the LiveData returned by the ViewModel. How are the new filtered results `observe()`'ed after selecting from the options menu?

Comment: @homerman when i click on a menu item, the method  `StocksActivity.fetchStocks()`  changes the ` allStock` variable from `StocksViewmodel`..at least that is the intention, or am i thinking wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`allStocks` may seem dynamic because it's `LiveData`, but remember that it's still a reference to an object in memory. When `StocksActivity` is created, it observes `allStocks` in it's initial state. For the sake of simplicity, let's say `allStocks` is pointing to an object in memory with the address of "A". When `selectAllStockWithFilter()` is eventually invoked, the `allStocks` handle is updated to point to a new instance of `LiveData` living in memory at address "B". The problem you're facing is that `StocksActivity` is still observing "A". Nothing communicated that the `allStocks` handle *itself* has been changed.

One way to resolve this would be to change `allStocks` into an instance of `MutableLiveData`. Subsequently, whenever the contents of this `allStocks` should be updated, instead of reassigning `allStocks`, you would update it's internal "value". This allows the `ViewModel` to pump new/updated values through the same `LiveData` object instance that `StocksActivity` is observing.

Something like this:

```
class StockViewModel(private val repo: StockRepository) : ViewModel() {

    ...

    val allStocks = MutableLiveData<List<Stock>>().apply { value = repo.selectAll() }


    ...

    fun selectAllStockWithFilter(filter: Int) {
        when (filter) {
            ALL -> allStocks.postValue(repo.selectAll())
            ORDER_BY_DESC -> allStocks.postValue(repo.selectAllOrderByDesc())
            ORDER_BY_ASC -> allStocks.postValue(repo.selectAllOrderByAsc())
            FINISHED -> allStocks.postValue(repo.selectAllFinished())
            UNFINISHED -> allStocks.postValue(repo.selectAllUnfinished())
        }
    }

    ...

}
```